# How to show the left-hand side of insert mode mappings while invoking them in Neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, insert-mode

Much like what was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391022/how-to-change-vim-insert-mode-mappings-behavior):

I want Neovim to show what I type, and keep recognising it as a mapping in progress even if I use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This is actually a very useful function that's in `vim-latex`, a famous plugin for LaTeX in Vim, called by the function `call IMAP()`. Is this implementable in other filetypes and buffers of Neovim/Vim, and if so, is there an example of this being implemented publically?

EDIT : Giving a clear example would be better for everyone, I was assured, so here goes an example:

Suppose I have an insert mode mapping of the following:

```
inoremap <buffer> hello helloworld
```

When I type `hello`, I want Vim to do the following:

```
h|
he|
hel|
hell|
hello|
helloworld|
```

However, Vim does the following:

```
|h
|e
|l
|l
|o
helloworld|
```

This is quite annoying since I can't know if I make a typo, and also requires me to type in very quick succession, which I am not really fond of. This, I hear, has something to do with the `ttimeout` option, which I have next to no knowledge of. Would this be enough of an example to better understand my question? I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but I really don't have a clue of how to phrase this...

Comment: As it stands, your question is a bit unclear to me: I suspect it’s missing relevant info from the question you linked. Could you please [edit] to clarify precisely what the desired functionality is (e.g., what modes you’re referring to, etc.)? [vi.se] prefers each question to stand on its own—links are acceptable, but only if the relevant info is also sufficiently contained in the post.

Comment: I've been trying to word this into clear statements for the last few hours to no avail; is it okay if I add a graphic (or textual) examples of what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: of course! Anything to make it clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is how mappings work, I don't think there is a way around it. You might try to use abbreviations instead, that work a bit like what you want.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know this feature even existed. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self: Use **abbreviations** (like [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/08.html))